# Secret sharing between a very large number of participants

Tags: secret-sharing

What can be a method for sharing a secret between a large number of participants?

With Shamir's Secret Sharing **(k,n)**, **n** can be arbitrarily large, but increasing **k** increases the complexity of the keys generation.

Is there an algorithm that can realistically generate keys for value of **k** between 1,000 and 1,000,000?

Comment: Must it be a k-out-of-n scheme or would n-out-of-n work? Also, what kind of efficiency improvements are you looking for? With Shamir, you get a linear increase in $k$. Are you looking for sub-linear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there an algorithm that can realistically generate keys for value of **k** between 1,000 and 1,000,000?

How about Shamir's Secret Sharing method?

For $k = 1000000$, generating a share would take a million field operations (multiplications and addition); this can be done in a few milliseconds per core (depending somewhat on the field you pick; there are CPU friendly ones out there).  Obviously, for the shares to be usable, you'll need to generate at least a million of them; this could be done in circa an hour on a laptop; that doesn't sound unrealistic to me.

If taking an hour to generate a million key shares is too expensive, what are the performance requirements?

Combining $k$ shares to reconstruct the secret takes $O(k)$ field operations; this is obviously quite reasonable; actually loading the shares is going to be the bulk of the work.

Comment: Yes k=1000000 within an hour sound realistic I was worried it would take a lot more.